# Returning empty value along with the list of items in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, knockout.js

I am working on a Knockout Js function which returns distinct list of items from an array using the following script

```
 self.products = ko.computed(function () {
        var products = ko.utils.arrayMap(ko.observableArray(self.datainput()).extendsdistinct('Product')(), function (item) {
            return item.Product;
        })
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(products);
    }, this);
```

The above script works fine but in my Array I have few empty items of type string which are not being returned.

For Example I have an array `["","","A","A","","B","C"]`

When I pass the above array to my function the result is `["A","B","C"]` but I always wanted it to be `["","A","B","C"]`

**May I know a good way to fix this?**

Comment: `ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(['','','A','B','','B','C'])` is returning  `['','A','B','C']` as expected.  Perhaps there is something weird in the `extendsdistinct`?

Comment: `ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(["","","A","A","","B","C"])[0] === ""` is true for me, double check `""` is in the input array